# Combine multiple VS2010 Projects to one .lib file

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio-2010

I want to combine a number of Win32 C-Projects to one .lib file.

OS: Windows XP Sp3
IDE/Comipler: Visual Studio 2010

Now I have one parent project that references all the other projects. But all the functions and globals from the referenced projects are not included or not public, so I get an "unresolved external" error when using the library.
Functions within the parent project function correctly.

What can I do?

---

There are some options for referencing projects but none of them seem to solve my problem

---

Even the /INCLUDE option in link.exe does not affect anything...

Comment: is it static lib? the simplest way would be to add all c-files to the parent project

Comment: If your child projects will all generate static libraries `.lib`, then you can try ` lib /out:lib_all.lib lib1.lib lib2.lib`. `lib.exe` is in **(your VC installation path)\bin**

Comment: @Stan; that constitutes an answer; why not post it as one?

Comment: @Clifford: because it's uncompleted :) and @Hint: Have you built a parent lib successfully? If so, try `dumpbin /exports yourParentLibFilename` to see the export symbols in your lib.

Comment: @Stan, I am not sure it is incomplete.  It exactly answers Hint's question; even if it does not solve his real problem.  He has made the error perhaps of asking how to implement what he thinks is a solution to a problem rather than asking how to solve the original problem.  There are many things that can be solved with yet another level of indirection, but this is probably not one of them ;)

Answer (score 3):

Finally I made it by defining the lib command as a make event (Post-Build Event).
lib /out:out.lib in1.lib lin2.lib ...

It is poorly portable but fits my requirements
Thanks @ Stan

Answer (score 0):

Referencing one project from another simply forces one project to be built as a dependency of another, it does not explicitly link the output of one with another.

You should configure the project dependencies so that the libraries are compiled first, then you must explicitly add the output of those projects (the static library, or the export library if the are DLL projects) to the linker "additional libraries" list.

You can as you suggest combine multiple libraries into one using the [Microsoft Library Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ykb2k5f.aspx?ppud=4), but that in itself is not a solution to your problem; you will still need to explicitly link the library as above to create an executable - there will just be one of them instead of several - I really cannot see there is much point in that unless the functionality is closely related, and if that were the case why are they not one project in the first instance?

If you are using the command line tools, then the [/INCLUDE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s3hwbhs%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) linker option will not help, that simply forces otherwise unreferenced object code to be included in the link.